# Best way to implement a search from a JSON API on a mobile app

Tags: ios, json, search, mobile

I have a JSON database with an API that I want to be able to search from a mobile app.

How should I go about implementing the search, especially if I want to do an incremental search that updates the results as the user types.

Should I load the data beforehand and just filter the results or should I get the data each time the search term changes?

How is it usually done?

Answer (score -1):

It depends on the amount of data being returned. If the dataset is small  you can do client side search but if its large you would have to do it server side and page it. Can you tell us more about what is being searched.

Comment: The entire dataset is about 30MB

Comment: I would do this server side with a type ahead control. The idea is the user enters in there search word and when the min number of characters is triggered then you send the query.